# Customizing joomla template (category, single, etc.)

Tags: templates, layout, joomla, structure, customization

It's possible to customize the template for **different types of content**... for example, on homepage: 1 column, on category listing: 2 columns, on single article: 3 columns. In Wordpress it's quite easy, modifying home.php, category.php, single.php.

**With what conditionals I can accomplish this in Joomla 1.5?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally display modules on a page by page basis (based on menu item). You can also assign completely different templates to each page. Furthermore, you can do things like

```
$option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
$view = JRequest::getCmd('view');
```

within your index.php and change the page based on the view/component.

Joomla's templating is excellent, with a lot of flexibility.

Comment: OK. I got the idea with JRequest::getCmd('option') and ('view'). With this variables I should work. For a single article, I should check for option=com_content&view=article. Am I right? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If only one column contains the real content (componenent/article) you could also work with collapsible module positions. Like this:

```
<?php if($this->countModules('left')) : ?>
    <div class="left_column">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="xhtml" />
    </div>
<?php endif; ?></code></pre>
```

Then the presence or absence of modules in this column will determine the layout.